# filter pandas dataframe with values of list of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, apply

I have the following two dataframes:

```
c_pd = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Geeks', 'Peter', 'James', 'Jack', 'Lisa'], 
               'england': ['fish and chips','cheese hamburger, roast beef, whatever','pizza peperoni, pizza marinera, wine','steak with french fries','potetos with tomato'], 
               'france': ['voiture, maison, petit dejeuner','voiture blanc, grand maison, whatever','ratatouille, vin','fromage','petit fromage']}) 

a_df = pd.DataFrame({'groups1':[['fromage blanc grand', 'petit dejeuner'],['la vache qui rie']],'groups2':[['Coq au vin','coq a la bier'],['cannard, vin']]}, index=['paragraph1','paragraph2'])
```

see visually the pic of the DFs at the end with expected result

I would like to add a column to the second DF b_df

```
land='france'
a_df['groups_1_dishes']=a_df['groups_1'].apply(lambda x: f(x,c_pd,land))
```

I want to apply a function that do the following.
For every element of the columns group_1 i would like to create in  group_1_dishes a column with the list of names of c_pd which complies with the condition that ALL the words of ANY of the elements of group_1 (comma=separator) are contained in the corresponding Name-land pair.

For instance:
for the first element of groups1 we have two elements of the list, 'white cheese' and 'red steak'. Any of the guys of table 1 visited Englang and France. And listed his favorite food/disches. I have to find out if the words WHITE and CHEESE are present in any of the "england" column. Are they? Yes they are, PETER has red steak and JACK has white cheeese. So the first result is the list [Peter,Jack]
lets do the second example. in for a_df.loc[['paragraph2'],['groups1']] we have [steak, salad, apple banana] so STEAK is in Peter list (remember, for every element in a_df all the words anywhere in the string of england). And SALAD is nowhere and 'APPLE' and 'BANANA' neither. So the result is just [Peter]

and the function takes in the land, because the same I would like to do with France, and further on with groups2 and both lands and so on ans so forth.

EXPECTED OUTPUT
See the new column added a_df['group_1_names']
[image]

So far I tried:

```
def f(list_of_disches,c_pd, land):
        
    # for instance the list_of_dishes would be here: ['fromage blanc grand', 'petit dejeuner']
    
    names_found=[]
    
    for dish in list_of_disches:
        # if all the words of sintagma are in concept add concept
        dish_words=dish.split() # for instance it would be ['fromage' 'blanc' 'grand']
        
        mask = c_pd[land].apply(any(lambda x: word in x for word in dish_words))
        
        names = c_pd[mask]['name'].tolist()

        names_found.append(names)
```

I think I am not far away but I can not manage

ADDED EDIT:Expected output

Comment: can you add your expected output?

Comment: It would be better if you post expected result for the sample dataset

Comment: I did now. Hope to see it graphically helps